# How to set limit to JSON schema object's value?

Tags: json, python-3.x, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

I want to check particular value for multiple entry in a json file. I wrote a JsonSchema but it is not show me correct result.

For example:

```
"student": [
                        {
                            "main": false, 
                            "name": "Robert"  
                        }, 
                        {
                            "main": true, 
                            "name": "Jannet"
                        },
                        {
                            "main": false, 
                            "name": "Julie"
                        }
                    ]
```

the json file will be validate if it has only one true for "main" and rest will be false. If it has multiple true it will not validate.
I tried the below jsonSchema:

```
"student":{
                                "type":"array",
                                "items":{
                                    "type":"object",
                                    "required":["name","main"],
                                    "properties":{
                                        "name":{
                                            "type":"string"
                                        },
                                        "main":{
                                            "type":"boolean"
                                        }
                                    },
                                            "anyOf":[
                                        {
                                            "properties":{
                                                "main":
                                                {
                                                "enum":[true]

                                                }   
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible with JSON Schema.

The only way this COULD be possible with JSON Schema is if you also required that the item in the array that is `main: true` is the first item.

If you CAN mandate this, let me know in a comment and I'll update this answer to explain how this would work.

Comment: @Json I tried ""main":{
           "type":"boolean",
           "contains":
           {"const": true},
           "minContains": 1,
           "maxContains": 1
           
          }" but it doesnt work

Comment: You're probably not using a validator that support draft 2019-09. It's relatively new.

Comment: I used "validator = jsonschema.Draft7Validator(schema)"

Comment: With draft-07, as you're OK with the first item being the ONLY one which may be `main:true`, I'll update my answer to reflect this.